Java BufferedImage: Drawing a pixel art image at its original pixel size causes pixel distortion
I am messing around with BufferedImages and I wanted to see if drawing an Pixel Art image at its original size and scaling it would be possible.
Before I even got to resizing it, I noticed that drawing the pixel art image at its native resolution caused some weird distortions and I don't know why or how to stop it. I am definitely not resizing the image and I've made sure to change the RenderingHints to nearest_neighbor. Is there something I am missing. I even loaded the file then saved it as a new file using:
File outputfile = new File("image.png");
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", outputfile);

[UPDATE] Here is the code snippet that I am using:
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class test extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage sprite;

    public test() {
        try {
            sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("floor.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(sprite, 10, 10, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        test sp = new test();
        frame.add(sp);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

Here is the output: https://i.sstatic.net/YJXJG.png
Here is what I am expecting: https://i.sstatic.net/8ilSr.png

The current code snippets are not enough to determine where the issue is. Please post the full, but minimal code to reproduce the problem as per the guidelines.

I updated it with as little code as possible. Even with this little, I still experience the problem. I am not sure why.

If you're talking about the bad or non-existent anti-aliasing then you should set hints for anti-aliasing in your code. It must be said however that Java is not particularly good at  anti-aliasing and you might therefore be better off using a vector image with Batik

im not looking to add anti-aliasing, I just want the original pixel image to be printed with pixels in its proper place.

tbh in that case, I don't actually see much between the two images, apart from anti-aliasing and size

Your screenshot is consistent with what I see when I run your code on a monitor at 125% resolution.
My Steps
I isolated your image here: 
When I run your code on my Windows computer and the monitor is at 125% resolution, here is what I see: 
The diagonal perimeter lines are a little jagged, like in your original post.
When I run your code on my Windows computer and the monitor is at 100% resolution, here is what I see: 
This appears to resolve the jagged/scaling problem.
Conclusion
At 125% monitor resolution: your image is being scaled automatically because your monitor is scaled.
Some options to improve this include:

Setting your monitor resolution to 100%.
Using high-quality rendering hints
Rescale your Graphics object. This can get complicated/messy, but if your use case is simple enough then (on some platforms, like on Windows) you can just use this method:

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // in this demo app: this basically strips away the OS's scaling
        ((Graphics2D)g).setTransform(new AffineTransform());
        g.drawImage(sprite, 10, 10, null);
    }

